# Как сделать связку commitEdit() и getValue()?

Tags: java, swing

Как мне реализовать вызов commitEdit в данном случае, чтобы получать getValue из форматтера? Читаю документацию https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#getValue() , но не понимаю пока до конца, как это работает...

```
public class MobileNumberForm extends JPanel {

    private JPanel rootPanel;
    private JFormattedTextField numberTextField;
    private JButton regButton;

    public MobileNumberForm() {
        try {
            numberTextField.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(getMaskFormatter()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addActionListenerForSwitchAction(ActionListener actionListener) {
        regButton.addActionListener(actionListener);
    }

    public JPanel getRootPanel() {
        return rootPanel;
    }

    public String getNumberTextField() {

                return (String) numberTextField.getValue();

    }


    public static MaskFormatter getMaskFormatter() throws ParseException {

        MaskFormatter  maskFormatter = new MaskFormatter("###########");
        maskFormatter.setValidCharacters("0123456789");
        maskFormatter.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');

        return maskFormatter;
    }
}
```

Comment: поясните, что вы хотите получить? опишите задачу, а не решение.

Comment: получить текущее редактируемое значение, установленное из MaskFormatter, как-то так

Comment: после нажатия на кнопку `regButton`?

Comment: да, чтобы возвращало на установки значения с MaskFormatter